# Getting undefined refrence in the copy constructors C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, undefined-reference

Hello i am trying to create a simple program in C++ and I have problems in linking the files. The error is *undefined reference* to my copy constructors in the classes. I checked the linking and I can't find any errors in the header file.

I tried messing around with the copy constructors but still no solution. when i comment the copy constructors, the program compiles.

**Error message:**

```
/tmp/cc5KI4Dx.o: In function `CenteredShape::CenteredShape(CenteredShape const&)':
Shapes.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `Shape::Shape()'
/tmp/cc5KI4Dx.o: In function `RegularPolygon::RegularPolygon(RegularPolygon const&)':
Shapes.cpp:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `CenteredShape::CenteredShape()'
/tmp/cc5KI4Dx.o: In function `Circle::Circle(Circle const&)':
Shapes.cpp:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to `CenteredShape::CenteredShape()'
/tmp/cc5KI4Dx.o: In function `Rectangle::Rectangle(Rectangle const&)':
Shapes.cpp:(.text+0x42c): undefined reference to `RegularPolygon::RegularPolygon()'
/tmp/cc5KI4Dx.o: In function `Square::Square(Square const&)':
Shapes.cpp:(.text+0x576): undefined reference to `RegularPolygon::RegularPolygon()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**testshapes.cpp**

```
#include "Shapes.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  Circle c("first circle", 3, 4, 7);
  RegularPolygon r("TRIANGLE", 1, 1, 3);

  r.printName();
  c.printName();

}
```

**Shapes.h**

```
/* 
    Classic shape examples: an inheritance tree in a geometric context
*/
#ifndef __SHAPES_H
#define __SHAPES_H
#include <string>

class Shape {           // base class
    private:                // private access modifier: could also be protected
        std::string name;   // every shape will have a name
    public:
        Shape(const std::string&);  // builds a shape with a name
        Shape();                    // empty shape
        Shape(const Shape&);
                // copy constructor
        void printName() const ;    // prints the name  

        //setters
        void setName(std::string newName);

        //getters
        std::string getName();

};

class CenteredShape : public Shape {  // inherits from Shape
    private: 
        double x,y;  // the center of the shape
    public:
        CenteredShape(const std::string&, double, double);  // usual three constructors
        CenteredShape();
        CenteredShape(const CenteredShape&);

        //setters
        void move(double, double);  // moves the shape, i.e. it modifies it center

        //getters
        double getX();
        double getY();

};

class RegularPolygon : public CenteredShape { // a regular polygon is a centered_shape with a number of edges
    private: 
        int EdgesNumber;
    public:
        RegularPolygon(const std::string&, double, double, int);
        RegularPolygon();
        RegularPolygon(const RegularPolygon&);

        //setters
        void setEdgesNumber(int newEdgesNumber);

        //getter 
        int getEdgesNumber();
    };

class Circle : public CenteredShape {  // a Circle is a shape with a center and a radius
    private:
        double Radius;
    public:
        Circle(const std::string&, double, double, double);
        Circle();
        Circle(const Circle&);

        //methods
        double perimeter();
        double area();

        //setters
        void setRadius(double newRadius);

        //getters
        double getRadius();

};

class Rectangle : public RegularPolygon {  // a Rectange is a shape with edges
    private:
        double length;
        double width;
    public:
        Rectangle(const std::string& n, double nx, double ny, double nwidth,double nheight);
        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(const Rectangle&);

        //methods
        double perimeter();
        double area();

        //setters
        void setLength(double newLength);
        void setWidth(double newWidth);

        //getters
        double getLength();
        double getWidth();

};

class Square : public RegularPolygon {  // a Square is a shape with edges
    private:
        double side;
    public:
        Square(const std::string& n, double nx, double ny, double nside);
        Square();
        Square(const Square&);

        //methods
        double perimeter();
        double area();

        //setters
        void setSide(double newSide);

        //getters
        double getSide();

};





#endif
```

**Shapes.cpp**

```
// please refer to shapes.h for methods documentation

#include <iostream>
#include "Shapes.h"

using namespace std; 
//------------------------------------------------------

Shape::Shape(const string& n) : name(n) {
}

// copy constructor
Shape::Shape(const Shape &shp)
{
    name = shp.name;
}       

void Shape::printName() const {
    cout << name << endl;
}

void Shape::setName(string newName)
{   
    name = newName;
}

string Shape::getName()
{
    return name;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------

void CenteredShape::move(double nx, double ny)
{
    x=nx;
    y=ny;
}

double CenteredShape::getX()
{
    return x;
}

double CenteredShape::getY()
{
    return y;
}

CenteredShape::CenteredShape(const string &n, double nx, double ny): Shape(n) {
    x = nx;
    y = ny;
}

CenteredShape::CenteredShape(const CenteredShape &cshp)
{
    x=cshp.x;
    y=cshp.y;

}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RegularPolygon::RegularPolygon(const string& n, double nx, double ny, int nl) : CenteredShape(n,nx,ny) 
{
    EdgesNumber = nl;
}

RegularPolygon::RegularPolygon(const RegularPolygon &regp)
{
    EdgesNumber=regp.EdgesNumber;
}


void RegularPolygon::setEdgesNumber(int newEdgesNumber)
{
    EdgesNumber=newEdgesNumber;
}

int RegularPolygon::getEdgesNumber()
{

    return EdgesNumber;
}



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
double Circle::perimeter()
{

    return (2*3.14*Radius);
}

double Circle::area()
{

    return(3.14*Radius*Radius);
}

void Circle::setRadius(double newRadius)
{
    Radius=newRadius;
}

double Circle::getRadius()
{
    return Radius;

}

Circle::Circle(const string& n, double nx, double ny, double r) : CenteredShape(n,nx,ny) 
{
    Radius = r;
}

Circle::Circle(const Circle &cr)
{
    Radius=cr.Radius;
}



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Rectangle::Rectangle(const string &n, double nx, double ny, double nwidth, double nheight) : RegularPolygon(n,nx,ny,4)
{
    length=nheight;
    width=nwidth;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(const Rectangle &rect)
{
    length=rect.length;
    width=rect.width;
}


double Rectangle::perimeter()
{
    return (2*(length+width));
}

double Rectangle::area()
{
    return (length*width);
}

void Rectangle::setLength(double newLength)
{
    length = newLength;
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(double newWidth)
{
    width = newWidth;
}

double Rectangle::getLength()
{
    return length;
}

double Rectangle::getWidth()
{
    return width;
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Square::Square(const string& n, double nx, double ny, double nside):RegularPolygon(n,nx,ny,4)
{

side=nside;

}

Square::Square(const Square &sqr)
{
    side = sqr.side;
}


double Square::perimeter()
{
    return (side*4);
}

double Square::area()
{
    return (side*side);
}

void Square::setSide(double newSide)
{
    side=newSide;
}

double Square::getSide()
{
    return side;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to define `CenteredShape::CenteredShape()`. You actually did not define any of the default consteuctors

Comment: I don't see a definition  for `Shape::Shape()` or `RegularPolygon::RegularPolygon()` either.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard. Just go through the list the compiler complains about one by one.

Comment: @BishoyAkmal I'm sorry if that sounded harsh, but it was meant as an encouragement. Sometimes when the compiler gives you a hard time you have to rethink the whole thing, but in this case it is just a short list of things to takes care of one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)